# How to create JAX-RPC stub/proxy files using WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jdeveloper, jax-rpc

I wanted to create `JAX-RPC stub/classes/proxy` files using my existing `WSDL` file. I used `wsimport`, but it just created class files. I tried `wscompile` but I was not sure about the required parameters. Could anyone suggest any tools, which is easy to use and help me to create required stub files from WSDL.

I'm using JDeveloper IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try Eclipse and use apache cxf libraries. It is an effective way to generate the proxy and stub for web services. It even provides the capability of mapping class names and package as per your requirements, however I do not have any experience using Jdeveloper IDE so I am unable to provide a proper comparison for same.

BR

Comment: I have already tried `apache cxf`. It just created class file only, which seems to be `JAX-WS` format, If I'm not wrong. But, I'm trying for `JAX-RPC` stubs.

Answer (score 0):

If your WSDL has RPC-style, wsimport will generate the client stubs for consuming RPC-style web services and similarly for document-style.

You may also want to check http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/